# Restrict area map with latitude and longitude in React Native

Tags: react-native, maps

I have a list page where I have latitude and longitude data of different items. I want to add a filter function to restrict the items to a certain radius. But how can I do that with latitude and longitude data?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ngeohash npm package to store the hash code of the locations that you have and filter the data as in the below example.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/nearby-location-queries-with-cloud-firestore-e7f4a2f18f9d

The above example using the firestore as a backend store but you also can use your own.

ngeohash npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngeohash